# How to "break" HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, simulation, load-testing, stress-testing

We are trying some tools to take a snapshot of Hbase and restore it.

I do't have experience of running live HBase so I don't know what problem we may encounter in the future which may leave HBase in a inconsistent state.

Does anyone know how simulate the real life to break our HBase data to test our snapshoting? Anything is appreciated, like bad code, bad shell command or even unplug network.

Answer (score 1):

- Store keys with large values (Megabyes) in a loop so that you run out of diskspace
- Mismatch Hadoop version with the one shipped in
- Set allowed number of opened files on the OS to a very low number
- Set JVM memory parameters to very low values (just enough to start HBase) and overload it with queries
- Set JVM memory parameters to very high values to cause intensive swapping
- Close ports or hard reboot nodes
- Soft reboot nodes

Some things I can think of :-)

Comment: Would love to see the results ;-) Probably via a blog post? Thanks!